# SQL group by without repeating fields same as excel pivot

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

What I need is the following.

Currently, it's repeating column names with the regular group by and sum.

```
| column 1    | column2     |  column3 | sum |
|-------------|-------------|----------|-----|
|main product |sub product1 |subsub 1  |  500|
|main product |sub product1 |subsub 2  |  300|
|main product |sub product2 |subsub 1  |  300|
```

I want to get rid of repeating the same as excel pivot, so below, I need.

```
| column 1    | column2     |  column3 | sum |
|-------------|-------------|----------|-----|
|main product |sub product1 |subsub 1  |  500|
|main product |             |subsub 2  |  300|
|main product |sub product2 |subsub 1  |  300|
```

Can someone help me with this?

edit : formatted

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

We can approximate this behavior with the help of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col3) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT col1, CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN col2 ELSE '' END AS col2, col3, sum
FROM cte t
ORDER BY col1, t.col2;
```

Comment: I'm upvoting, but in this case, the better `order by` is `order by col1, rn`, just in case there are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select col1, 
       case when row_number() over(partition by col1, col2 order by col3) = 1 then col2 else 0 end as col2, 
       col3, sum
from table t
group by col1, col2, col3;
```